# Galaxy SII not reporting Signal Strength

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, network-signal

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy SII which in general has worked perfectly for me. My only issue is that the phone won't report the signal strength. If I get to the phone information (using the * # * # 4636 # * # code) the system reports the signal strength as zero which is impossible (since I have loads of reception issues in my home). My guess is that the information is being blocked, but I don't know why or how to unblock it.

The phone is running in GSM/WCDMA (Auto Mode) with the stock ROM

Comment: I'm confused by "loads of reception issues in my home" - are you sure 0 signal isn't accurate? Otherwise, what are your network stats in `About Phone > Status`? Specifically Service and Mobile Network States.

Comment: The signal is measured in dB and the more negative the number, the worse the signal is. Therefore, the fact that the phone is reading zero is in itself an issue, since a signal strength close to zero would mean an excellent signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is related to this issue: [onSignalStrengthsChanged returns unknown signal strength](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18336) where android return wrong strength on Galaxy S2.